# draggable objects and canvas in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, draggable

I have three questions. The first question is the most important but I appreciate to get answers to the others.

---

First question, see this jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/owLdgrdq/10

```
//copia nariz
$(document).on('click', '#add-nariz', function(){
    var a = $('#add-nariz');
  var src = a.attr('src');
  var elem = $('<img class="objetos" src="' + src + '" width="30px" height="30px" style="positon: relative;" />');
  $('#fotoAlterada').append(elem);
  elem.draggable();
});
//copia bolinha azul
$(document).on('click', '#add-bb', function(){
    var a = $('#add-bb');
  var src = a.find('img:first').attr('src');
  var elem = $('<img class="objetos" src="' + src + '" width="30px" height="30px" style="positon: relative;" />');
  $('#fotoAlterada').append(elem);
  elem.draggable();
});

$(document).on('click', '#salvaImagem', function(){

  var m = $('#foto');
  var totX = parseInt(m.css('width'));
  var totY = parseInt(m.css('height'));
  var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  c.width = totX;
  c.height = totY;
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  alert(totX + '\n' + totY);

  var base = document.getElementById('foto');
  ctx.drawImage(base,0,0,totX,totY,0,0,totX,totY);

  var posicoes = [];
  $(".objetos").each(function(){
    var img = $(this);
    x = parseInt(img.css("left"))+totX;
    y = parseInt(img.css("top"))+totY;
    altura = parseInt(img.css("width"));
    largura = parseInt(img.css("height"));
    posicoes.push([ 
     x,
     y,
     largura,
     altura
    ]);
  });
  alert( JSON.stringify(posicoes));
  var j;
  var numAderecos = posicoes.length;
  for(j = 0; j < numAderecos; j++){
    ctx.drawImage(base,posicoes[j][0],posicoes[j][1],posicoes[j][2],posicoes[j][3]);
  }

});
```

I have some icons (Adicionar isto:) what I want add to a photo (Editar isto:). When the user clicks on the icons, a copy is made beside the photo. More click make more copies. These copies are draggable. The user choose the position of the objects and click in a button to save ("Salvar Mudanças"). This button makes a copy of the original photo with the new objects on it (inside a canvas).

At final of the JS code I put little photos (same as original) as little objects added to the photo in the canvas, but just because I don't know how to copy each object added. How can I do that?

---

Second question, when click on the button, the positions are not the same in the canvas, they are pull to down a little (and left too). Why is this happening if I put padding and margin 0px in CSS code?

---

Third question, the variable 'base' I used $('#foto') to get by id, but I can't use it at canvas arguments. When I use document.getElementById('foto') I can. What is the difference among them?

----editing ----

My aim with this is to make a mobile application, through cordova/phonegap. The user must be able to get a picture from the device or a selfie with the cam (it's already ok). When the picture/photo is gotten, some new objects like a crown's nose, colorful hat and other silly things appear on the window (it's ok, just change style="display: none;" to be displayed), when the user clicks on these things they make a copy at the bottom of the photo and these copies must be draggable (it's nice too). Then, with jQuery-UI I'm getting the position of all dragged objects into the photo, the user clicks on a button "Salvar Mudanças" ("save changes"), and this action copy the photo plus objects to a canvas area (this is the way I got to make the app). After, the user clicks on another button to share the modified image (in canvas) through whatsapp, facebook, email and any other way which the device could do.

Comment: Instead of using jQueryUI to drag an img element onto canvas, how about dividing a single canvas into a toolbar with source images at the top and your husky image at the bottom? Then you can use simple image dragging techniques to apply your image-copies to the husky.

Comment: Lemme see if I understood. I put a canvas tag and inside that I put some divs? I think I don't understand why this is easier. Can you explain me more, please? Thanks (I'm gonna edit my question to explicit my aim with this)

Comment: No divs in the canvas -- that's not possible. Just draw your tool icons at the top of the canvas and your husky at the bottom of the canvas. Let the user drag the icons onto the husky. Everything is a drawing on the canvas. I've added an answer with an example of this alternate method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is an alternate way of appending icons onto an image using just a canvas**

- Carve out a toolbar area at the top of an html5 canvas and fill it with your desired icons.
- Put the destination image below the toolbar.
- Listen for mouse events.
- Allow the user to icons from the toolbar onto the image below.
- When the user "drops" the dragging icon by releasing the mouse, create a duplicate of the dragged icon at the dropped position.

**Here is annotated code and a Demo:**

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isDown=false;
var startX,startY;

ctx.lineWidth=0.50;
ctx.strokeStyle='lightgray';
ctx.fillStyle='white';

// vars for icons, etc
var tbar={width:cw,height:35}
var tw=30;
var th=30;
var dragging=null;
var dropped=[];
var icons=[
  {name:'Flower',x:tw*0,y:2,url:'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/flower.png'},
  {name:'Star',x:tw*1,y:2,url:'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/star.png'},
  {name:'Plane',x:tw*2,y:2,url:'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/plane2.png'},
  {name:'Mario',x:tw*3,y:2,url:'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/marioStanding.png'},
];
  var thumbs=[];
var mainImg=new Image();
mainImg.crossOrigin='anonymous';
mainImg.onload=start;
mainImg.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/husky.jpg';
var imgCount=icons.length+1;
for(var i=0;i<icons.length;i++){
  var icon=icons[i];
  icon.index=i;
  icon.img=new Image();
  icon.img.crossOrigin='anonymous';
  icon.img.onload=start;
  icon.img.src=icon.url;
}

// start is called when each image is fully loaded
function start(){
  // wait for all images to load
  if(--imgCount>0){return;}
  // create 
  for(var i=0;i<icons.length;i++){
    var icon=icons[i];
    thumbs.push(thumb(icon.img,tw,th));
  }
  // draw the toolbar & image
  draw();
  // listen for mouse events
  $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
  $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
  $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});
  $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});
}

// create thumbnails for each image (to be used as icons in the toolbar)
function thumb(img,w,h){
  var iw=img.width;
  var ih=img.height;
  var s=Math.min((w/iw),(h/ih))
  var c=document.createElement('canvas');
  c.width=iw*s;
  c.height=ih*s;
  c.getContext('2d').drawImage(img,0,0,iw,ih,0,0,iw*s,ih*s);
  return(c);
}

// draw the toolbar, image & any clone thumbnails added to the image
function draw(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,tbar.height);
  ctx.strokeRect(0,0,cw,tbar.height);
  ctx.drawImage(mainImg,0,tbar.height);
  for(var i=0;i<icons.length;i++){
    var icon=icons[i];
    ctx.drawImage(thumbs[icon.index],icon.x,icon.y);
  }
  for(var i=0;i<dropped.length;i++){
    var icon=dropped[i];
    ctx.drawImage(thumbs[icon.thumbIndex],icon.x,icon.y);
  }
  if(dragging){
    ctx.drawImage(thumbs[dragging.thumbIndex],dragging.x,dragging.y);
  }
}

//
function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // get the mouse position
  startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  // hit test the toolbar icons and any dropped icons
  var mx=startX;
  var my=startY;
  // hit test toolbar icons
  if(mx>0 && mx<tw*icons.length && my>2 && my<2+tw){
    var icon=icons[parseInt(mx/tw)];
    dragging={thumbIndex:icon.index,x:icon.x,y:icon.y};
    dragging.source='icons';
    return;
  }
  // hit test dropped icons
  for(var i=0;i<dropped.length;i++){
    var icon=dropped[i];
    if(mx>icon.x && mx<icon.x+tw && my>icon.y && my<icon.y+th){
      dragging=dropped[i];
      dragging.source='dropped';
      dragging.droppedIndex=i;
      return;
    }
  }
}

// Add any 
function handleMouseUpOut(e){
  if(!dragging){return;}
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  //
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  // add the icon to its dropped position
  if(dragging.source=='icons'){
    if(dragging.y>tbar.height){
      dropped.push(dragging);
    }
    // remove the dropped icon if it's back in the toolbar
  }else if(dragging.y<tbar.height){
    dropped.splice(dragging.droppedIndex,1);
  }
  // clear dragging
  dragging=null;
  // redraw
  draw();
}

// move any icon that's being dragged
function handleMouseMove(e){
  if(!dragging){return;}
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // get mouse position
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  // move the dragged icon by the distance the mouse
  // has moved since the last mousemove event
  var dx=mouseX-startX;
  var dy=mouseY-startY;
  startX=mouseX;
  startY=mouseY;
  dragging.x+=dx;
  dragging.y+=dy;
  // redraw
  draw();
}

// save just the image with dropped icons
$('#save').click(function(){
  var c=document.createElement('canvas');
  c.width=cw;
  c.height=ch-tbar.height;
  c.getContext('2d').drawImage(canvas,0,tbar.height,cw,ch-tbar.height,0,0,c.width,c.height);
  var img=new Image();
  img.onload=function(){
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  }
  img.src=c.toDataURL();
});
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid lightgray; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='save'>Save</button>
<h4>Drag from top toolbar & icon will be drop-copied<br>Drag dropped icons around image<br>Drag dropped icon back to toolbar to delete.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tough to follow, but I suspect you're asking about compositing all of the existing DOM images onto a single canvas context. For that you'll probably want to look at the `globalCompositeOperation` property on the 2dcanvas:

[globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) - the property

[Compositing Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Compositing) - basic outline of how the different types work

---

Also your 3rd question: `$('#foto')` returns a jquery object, and `document.getElementById` returns a DOM object. To get the actual DOM element you would do something like: `var theEl = $('#foto')[0]`